# Scrollview under the header

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to do this in android studio? I want to achieve that when you scroll down the header will overlap above and under is the scrollview part. What I've got is it scrolls over the header. [In android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhwQ0.png)

This is what Im trying to achieve that was made in figma

[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4gGX.png)

[When you scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JJ4L.png)

So far this is what my code looks like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Fragment.RecordFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_header"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Record"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="35sp" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
                android:text="Date for today"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="316dp"
                    android:layout_height="201dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sec_bp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="SBP" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="DBP" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="BPM" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="save" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="316dp"
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/sec_temp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="316dp"
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/sec_temp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post a image or video of what type of output you want

Comment: @primo when you click the link, that's the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding **elevation** inside your header view. like this :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="369dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_header"/
    android:elevation="1dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:text="Record"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="35sp" 
    android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

I set the View elevation 1dp and the TextView 2dp so that the text can still in front of the View.